# I get the error :[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:

Tags: python, error-handling

this code moves all pdf files into a folder called pdf.It moves the first file then get error for moved file: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\Users\farbod\Desktop\Print Form.pdf' -> 'C:/Users/farbod/Desktop/pdf/Print Form.pdf'
note: I also used shutil instead of pathlib.Same error

```
import os
from pathlib import Path




path ="C:/Users/farbod/Desktop"
pdf_folder_path = "C:/Users/farbod/Desktop/pdf"
files=[]

os.chdir(path)
files = os.listdir(path)
for file in files:
    file_path= path + '/' + file
    file_name,file_ext= os.path.splitext(file_path)
    if file_ext==".pdf":
        os.rename(file_path,pdf_folder_path+'/'+file)
        Path(file_path,).rename(pdf_folder_path+'/'+file)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Is the file in the `pdf` subdirectory? If so, that's the issue: you're only calling `os.listdir()` on the parent directory. Look at something like `os.walk` instead to be able to recursively descend into any and all subdirectories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed and working code.Thank you Mr. Ghost Ops

```
import os


pdf_folder_path = "/pdf/"

os.chdir("C:/Users/farbod/Desktop")
files = os.listdir()
for file in files:
    file_path= f"{file}"
    file_name,file_ext= os.path.splitext(file_path)
    if file_ext==".pdf":
        #your if statement didnt work because i had a folder called pdf.
        os.rename(file_path,"C:/Users/farbod/Desktop/pdf"+"/"+file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the code you are looking for

Tell me if there's any errors

```
import os
# from pathlib import Path

os.chdir("C:/Users/farbod/Desktop")
files = os.listdir()
for file in files:
    if file.split('.')[-1] == "pdf":
        os.rename(file, f"/pdf/{file}")
        # Path(file).rename(f"/pdf/{file}")
        # I can't understand why you have to move a file using 2 same functioning lines
        # (or guess what, i don't know to use pathlib. os.rename is enough to move a file)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really helpful. I did a debugging in your code and now it works errorles.

Comment: Accept the answer and close the question dude if its done...
Or atleast mark the correct answer (yours) it'll be helpful for others